# Is there any way to check which IDE was used to create .Net project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I`m using Visual Studio for .NET projects. I would like to know if I open my project later in any open source IDE, can someone check that it was created with Visual studio?

Comment: Open source IDE like ?

Comment: SharpDevelop for example

Comment: I remembered the project files' icon of VS and SD are different.

Comment: it`s not a problem to change the icon, main thing is that i need to know what to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you edit the solution file (.sln) with a text editor, you can see in the 3rd line which Visual Studio version was used to create the solution.

```
# Visual Studio 14
```

In the 4th line you can see the exact version. This is the indicator that the solution was created by VS.

```
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
```

SharpDevelop for example writes in the 4th line

```
# SharpDevelop 5.1
```